# How to fix: 'No suitable method for newHandler'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to write Spring Application. My main function looks like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
        final BookServices bookService = new BookServices();
        final BookAPI bookAPI = new BookAPI(bookService);
        final RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction = RouterFunctions.
                nest(RequestPredicates.path("/"), bookAPI.routerFunction);
        final HttpHandler httpHandler = toHttpHandler(routerFunction);
        final ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(HOST, PORT);
        server.newHandler(adapter).block();
}
```

Unfortunatelly, this line raises an error:

```java
        server.newHandler(adapter).block();
```

Error:

```java
java: no suitable method found for newHandler(org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter)
    method reactor.ipc.netty.NettyConnector.newHandler(java.util.function.BiFunction<? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerRequest,? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse,? extends org.reactivestreams.Publisher<java.lang.Void>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter cannot be converted to java.util.function.BiFunction<? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerRequest,? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse,? extends org.reactivestreams.Publisher<java.lang.Void>>)
    method reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServer.newHandler(java.util.function.BiFunction<? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerRequest,? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse,? extends org.reactivestreams.Publisher<java.lang.Void>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter cannot be converted to java.util.function.BiFunction<? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerRequest,? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse,? extends org.reactivestreams.Publisher<java.lang.Void>>)
```

I m using Spring 2.1.5

Comment: what is it you want to do? run a spring webflux server?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf yes

Comment: then please look at a tutorial how to build one because you are way off.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/

Comment: @ThomasAndolf yeah, indeed I got wrong thinking.